# Direct product norm

Tags: linear-algebra

Given a norm on $V$ say $||*||$, what is the norm on $V \times V$? Can we induce this norm from $||*||$?

Please help with understanding this.

Comment: You are mistaken in thinking that there is such a thing as "the" norm. There may be infinitely many norms on any space.

Comment: that was the question,I wanted to know whether there is "the" norm,I was hoping that there is to solve my problem here...

Comment: Although there may be many norms, all norms on a finite-dimensional space are topologically equivalent (they all induce the same topology). This is false in the case of infinite-dimensional spaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V$ x  $V$ consists of ordered pairs $(v_1,v_2)$. One can define a norm on $V $ x $V$ in various ways: For example a norm $||.||$ on $V$ x $V$ can be given by:

$||(v_1,v_2)||=||v_1||+||v_2||$.

Another norm could be:

$||(v_1,v_2)||=max\{||v_1||,||v_2||\}$

Comment: thank you for such a quick response, I thought about this,my problem is given norm $||*||$ on V to show that the map $(v_1,v_2)\rightarrow v_1+v_2$ is continous, i was hoping that we could induce norm $||*||_{x}$ on $V \times V$ by saying $||(v_1,v_2)||_x= ||v_1||+||v_2||$.But this way it doesnt work, can you advise me smth on this matter?

Comment: In what way does $\|(v_1, v_2)\| = \|v_1\| + \|v_2\|$ not work for you?

Comment: Since we dont know what norm is there on $V \times V$ according to your answer,we cannot take this norm...